# Generating running configuration for postfix

Tags: postfix, dovecot

When I run `dovecot -n`, dovecot generate all of running configuration. Now, I need same for `postfix`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's no single command to give all running configuration at once, as any Postfix [component](http://www.postfix.org/OVERVIEW.html) can have [multiple instances on a single host](http://www.postfix.org/MULTI_INSTANCE_README.html) through `master.cf`, meaning there can be multiple running configurations at the same time.

Acknowledging this, take a look at [`postconf` - Postfix configuration utility](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.1.html):

> - `-p` Show `main.cf` parameter settings. This is the default.
> - `-P` Show `master.cf` service parameter settings (by default all  services and all parameters), formatted as
>   `service/type/parameter=value`, one per line.  Specify `-Pf` to fold
>   long lines.
> - `-n` Show only configuration parameters that have explicit `name=value` settings  in  `main.cf`.